# python import cx_Oracle error in command window

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

I'm having trouble running some codes that import cx_Oracle in command line, though the same codes work in console. Is there anything else I will need to set up in order to get this to work via command line please?

1. Saved just one line of code "import cx_Oracle" as  test.py.
2. Run this line in ide (Spyder), iPython Notebook => no issues
3. run this by opening a command line window from the same folder the .py file is saved in, and run python test.py and encounter the below:

   ```
   import cx_Oracle
   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
   ```

Not sure if there is anything additional I will need to set up to run cx_Oracle via command line? Have tried all the suggestions on setting PATH, ORACLE_HOME, re-installing but could not get this to work. versions that i'm using are

Python: 2.7
cx_Oracle: cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win-amd64-py2.7
instant client: 12.1.0.0
Windows: 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I also found this kind of problem.
Look at "not a valid Win32 application" this sentence, so I decide to change cx_Oracle to cx_Oracle-5.1.3-11g.win-32-py2.7. Luckly, it does work.